# When to use export default and export constant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am currently working on a react meteor project. 
I didn't find any clear documentation when to exactly use `export default` and when `export const`.
Any opinions on this respectively when to use what and what are the differences?

Answer (score 15):

`export default` exports your module with no name, you can thus import it with this syntax :

```
export default MyModule = () => console.log('foo')

import MyModule from './MyModule' //it works
import foobar from './MyModule' //it also works,
```

`export const` exports with name :

```
export const MyModule = () => console.log('foo')

import MyModule from './MyModule' //returns empty object since there is no default export
import { MyModule } from './MyModule' //here it works because by exporting without 'default' keyword we explicitly exported MyModule
```

- So, when you're exporting only one element from your module and you don't care of its name, use `export default`.
- If you want to export some specific element from your module and you do care of their names, use `export const`
- You should notice that you can combine both, in case you want to import a specific module by default and let the user import specific elements of your module.